# gdal or gnuplot projection with c++

Tags: c++, plot, gnuplot, gdal, map-projections

I want to plot the geography with given value longitude, latitude and the color representative (basically three columns data, i.e., 60.5, 80, 234). Does anyone have such experience or idea for this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you start with sharing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to learn gnuplot library with this link: http://stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/. But it's only suitable for two-dimensional plotting. And I did not find any useful example with gdal.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you are aiming too high - you want to achieve too much with too little knowledge. I don't think somebody will be able to help you here. My advice is - start with a small project, with code that actually works, and take it from there. Once you have a real problem with real code, come back.

Comment: thank you very much, vaettchen. I will try to find a hint and get started.